# Can't delete preferred networks from wireless settings (comes back up)

Tags: macos, ios, wifi, keychain

I am having an issue with **preferred networks** in WiFi settings. There are few networks I want to **delete** - when I do so, the disappear temporarily, but will **eventually come back**. I believe is to do with iCloud saving passwords.

Let's say I delete network from my iPhone (also on my macbook), after day or two I will notice my iPhone or Macbook connecting to the same hotspot again (shared, so this is a security issue), and I will go in to preferred network settings and will see all the networks I have already deleted.

Do any of you have a similar issue?

Because of security issue I had to enable password protection for network switching on my macbook, and keep wifi disabled when unused on my iPhone.

I have also submitted bug report to Apple, but did not get any response or comments back.